# Creating a selector for a value that is itself an escaped selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

The code:

```
<p id='P1"'>Hello World</p>
<datalist id="foo">
<option value='#P1\"' />
</datalist>
```

I discovered that by escaping symbol characters (such as " in the example above) I could create a CSS selector to work with jQuery to select elements with symbol characters in their IDs. I put this selector in a datalist.

The question is how can a write a query to get the option from the datalist?

```
const datalist = document.getElementById("foo");
datalist.querySelector('option[value="???"]');

//or

$("#foo > option[value="???"]');
```

I tried with

```
'#P1\"'
'#P1\\\"'
```

And when I just put "#P1" in the datalist, I successfully retrieved it with

```
option[value="#P1"]
```

I'm just stumped on how to get the answer to the value as shown above.

Comment: using `\ ` only escapes whatever value before it and doesn't actually "exist" so you should select `#P1"` i could be wrong though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need double escaping. This is how I found that out:

```js
// how does it look this way?
console.log(document.querySelector(`#foo > option[value^='#P1']`));
// aha!
console.log(document.querySelector(`#foo > option[value='#P1\\\\"']`));
// jQuery too?
console.log($(`#foo > option[value='#P1\\\\"']`)[0]);
// how about value="\☺"?
console.log(document.querySelector(`#foo > option[value='\\\\☺']`));

// fun use
document.body.appendChild( Object.assign( document.createElement("div"), {
    style: "font-size:4rem; top:-15px;position:absolute;left:5rem;",
    innerHTML: document.querySelector(`#foo > option[value='\\\\☺']`).value.slice(1), 
  } )
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='P1"'>Hello World</p>
<datalist id="foo">
<option value='#P1\"' />
<option value="\☺" />
</datalist>
```

Comment: Thank you (+1) for this. I'm still struggling in my mind with "double escaping" - it makes sense, but I've got to work hard to work it out.

Comment: Glad I could help. Same here btw, it's a bit strange.

Comment: BTW, after some research: `<option value="#P1&#x22;"/>` would allow you to use `option[value='#P1"']`

Comment: Yeah but the whole point of this being in the datalist is/was to help my users find and use id selectors. So encoding in the option field is going to be too confusing for them. Going through this, you are helping me in considering whether it's worth it to accept IDs like this, rather than just flag them for the user to correct. I am now thinking the latter is lower risk, whereas supporting such IDs has the potential to create so many problems. Thank you!